# Chave estrangeira no phpMyAdmin traz registro duplicado

Tags: banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin, chave-estrangeira

**Problema**

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada "entidades_categoria-script" (chamemos de 'A') que possui as seguintes chaves:

[image: Chaves da TABELA A]

Acontece que ela faz referência a outra tabela chamada entidades_categoria-script-tipo (chamemos apenas de 'B'), que possui apenas os seguintes registros:

[image: Registros da TABELA B]

Daí, no phpMyAdmin, quando eu tento inserir um novo registro na tabela A a seguinte situação acontece:

[image: Registros duplicados no campo da chave estrangeira]

**Portanto**

O que estaria fazendo com que o SELECT mostrasse em seus options os itens da TABELA B nesse formato? O esperado seria "id - nome", mas ele acaba por mostrar "id - nome; nome - id" ou isso é um comportamento padrão no phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Desculpe mas você não explicou qual o problema. Foi exibido algum erro? Talvez um SELECT com o respectivo resultado possa clarear qual é a dúvida.

Comment: O SELECT que você sugeriu foi apresentado na terceira figura da minha pergunta. Se você verificar a tabela B, pode ver que nela só estão cadastrados dois itens, ao passo que o SELECT mostra 6, pois ele acaba por trazer dois valores em branco, além dos dois registros pré-cadastrados invertidos (nome - id; id - nome). O resultado esperado seria apenas (id - nome).

Comment: Desculpe mas você não apresentou o código do SELECT e o que você diz que é resultado do que, presumo, seria um JOIN não me parece crível com os dados que você diz existirem na tabela entidades_categoria-script-tipo.

Comment: Mas não é da minha aplicação que eu estou falando. Aquela imagem é do próprio phpMyAdmin. Não fui eu que programei. Ela é acessada via menu "INSERIR" depois que eu clico na tabela desejada. Trata-se de uma dúvida sobre a interface do gerenciador de banco de dados.Eu não inseri nenhuma sentença SQL ou JOIN. Apenas configurei a FK tal como apresentado.